# Nested Array mapping restkit v.20

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, restkit, object-object-mapping

i wanna to map object in Google Places Api Photos

```
  "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 1224,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://plus.google.com/105663944571530352563\"\u003eJoshua Gilmore\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CnRoAAAAzuH4E1LVJHMdXNYbewoxcPE-qHizCE6pmOGjckeaCTKSL7xGVzLuwGxu7kx44bCWIZinMx4jkd8eenALB7w7jNRFrzE3hip2ld7096SI9D4sE2WpXQ1QH-iTQm7qhx4i6QSGGeXKjA9SfT4N6krwzRIQr1mulgyuKHP-2s_TJWIahhoUgxfccds3VAH2bj_CIQYzbAQZRhc",
               "width" : 1632
            }
         ],
```

i try with this code but photos is still nil

Place Class

```
@interface Place : NSObject    
@property (nonatomic,strong) Geometry * geometry;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString * icon;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString * placeID;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic,strong) OpeningHours * opening_hours;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString * price_level;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString * rating;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString * vicinity;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray *photos;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *reference; 
@end
```

Photos Class

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Photos : NSObject
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSNumber *height;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *html_attributions;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *photo_reference;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSNumber *width;
@end
```

And i map with:

```
 RKObjectMapping *placeMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Place class]];
    [placeMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
     @"icon" : @"icon",
     @"id" : @"placeID",
     @"name" : @"name",
     @"reference" : @"reference",
     @"price_level" : @"price_level",
     @"rating" : @"rating",
     @"vicinity" : @"vicinity",
     }];



RKObjectMapping* photosMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Photos class]];
    [photosMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"height",@"photo_reference",@"html_attributions",@"width"]];

    [placeMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"photos"
                                                                                 toKeyPath:@"photos"
                                                                               withMapping:photosMapping]];
```

I don't know how to map photos as array in Place Class . 
Any one can help me ?

Comment: How is photos defined on your place object?

Comment: Can you post the code for your place and photos classes? First off, you probably want to add attribute mappings from a dictionary and not an array so that you can map from "photo_reference" to your NSString named "photoReference". But yeah... need to see your data models to tell if you have it set up correctly.